# Programmatically create SSRS Report in PDF from MVC 2

Tags: model-view-controller, pdf, reporting-services, parameters

How can i create a SQL Server 2008 R2 PDF Report programmatically from within an MVC 2 Application?

i want need to pass a parameter to SSRS.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Microsoft's documentation on this topic, it is quite verbose.

http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms154052%28SQL.90%29.aspx