# Create PDF file without the MS Office

Tags: c#

I have to create a PDF report by returning some data from the DB.
How to create PDF files without using the MS Office? Can I use SSRS ? 
If yes how can I do it? 
But I don't want to use the Crystal Reports..

Comment: A quick Google search yields much - https://www.google.com/search?q=create+PDF+with+c%23&aq=f&oq=create+PDF+with+c%23&aqs=chrome.0.57j0j60j0l2.6164&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: What have you tried? What data do you have? What kind of document do you want? There is so little detail to go on here that it's impossible to answer.  (For example: you *could* create a PDF file by copying an existing one, but I doubt that's a useful solution to many problems...)

Comment: Is this a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4696736/programmatically-create-ssrs-report-in-pdf-from-mvc-2

Comment: Hi Dan Puzey, I am trying to create a letter by using some data like address , name etc for the DB. but I already tried using word to PDF and I don't want to use this method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest **iTextSharp**, a C# port of the **iText** java library that is very easy to use. It can be found on the following [link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/). I used it few years a lot for generating pdf documents in ASP.NET projects.